# Javascript - Changing button image depending on device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, button

I am trying to display the correct button and link depending on what device the user browses to a page on. If android display android app store button if ios display apple store button.

I cannot seem to get it to swap at all even though im making the function default to swap it from android to apple button.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var apple = "/images/ios.jpg";
        var android = "/images/android.jpg"


        function DetectDevice() {
            var but = document.getElementById("AppButton");
            if(useragent.search("iphone") || useragent.search("ipod") || useragent.search("ipad")) {
                toswap.src = apple;
                alert("apple");
            } else if(useragent.search("android")) {
                toswap.src = android;
                alert("android");
            }
            but.src = apple;
        }
        DetectDevice();
    </script>

    <title>Device Detection</title>
</head>

<div id="butttons">
    <img src="images/android.jpg" name = "AppButton" id="AppButton"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two issues:**

First, your function needs to run *after* the button has loaded because

```
document.getElementById("AppButton");
```

is returning nothing at the moment.

Secondly, you should probably change 2 instances of `toswap.src` to `but.src`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where var toswap refers to.  Try this:

```
        var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var apple = "/images/ios.jpg";
        var android = "/images/android.jpg"


        function DetectDevice() {
            var but = document.getElementById("AppButton");
            if(useragent.search("iphone") || useragent.search("ipod") || useragent.search("ipad")) {
                but.src = apple;
                alert("apple");
            } else if(useragent.search("android")) {
                but.src = android;
                alert("android");
            } else{
                but.src = apple; // this is default
            }
        }

    </script>

<div id="butttons">
    <img src="images/android.jpg" onload="DetectDevice();" name = "AppButton" id="AppButton"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`useragent` is not defined either. You may have meant to use `uagent` which you defined, or you may have meant to rename your variable.